# Showing the result in a quiz app + incorrect/correct dialogs

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I am just reposting since my last post was (kinda) fixed and I am facing a new problem. The quiz now shows if the answer is correct or incorrect but there's a problem in the code.

1. the answers SOMETIMES shows the wrong dialog (correct answer shows incorrect, incorrect answer shows correct) and sometimes it's right.

```
public class MainGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FButton buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, buttonD;
    TextView questionText, triviaQuizText, timeText, resultText, coinText;
    TriviaQuizHelper triviaQuizHelper;
    TriviaQuestion currentQuestion;
    List<TriviaQuestion> list;
    int qid = 0;
    int timeValue = 20;
    int coinValue = 0;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    Typeface tb, sb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_main);

        //Initializing variables
        questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviaQuestion);
        buttonA = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        buttonB = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
        buttonC = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
        buttonD = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
        triviaQuizText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviaQuizText);
        timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeText);
        resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
        coinText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coinText);

        //Setting typefaces for textview and buttons - this will give stylish fonts on textview and button etc
        tb = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/TitilliumWeb-Bold.ttf");
        sb = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/shablagooital.ttf");
        triviaQuizText.setTypeface(sb);
        questionText.setTypeface(tb);
        buttonA.setTypeface(tb);
        buttonB.setTypeface(tb);
        buttonC.setTypeface(tb);
        buttonD.setTypeface(tb);
        timeText.setTypeface(tb);
        resultText.setTypeface(sb);
        coinText.setTypeface(tb);

        //Our database helper class
        triviaQuizHelper = new TriviaQuizHelper(this);
        //Make db writable
        triviaQuizHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        //It will check if the ques,options are already added in table or not
        //If they are not added then the getAllOfTheQuestions() will return a list of size zero
        if (triviaQuizHelper.getAllOfTheQuestions().size() == 0) {
            //If not added then add the ques,options in table
            triviaQuizHelper.allQuestion();
        }

        //This will return us a list of data type TriviaQuestion
        list = triviaQuizHelper.getAllOfTheQuestions();

        //Now we gonna shuffle the elements of the list so that we will get questions randomly
        Collections.shuffle(list);

        //currentQuestion will hold the que, 4 option and ans for particular id
        currentQuestion = list.get(qid);

        //countDownTimer
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(22000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                //here you can have your logic to set text to timeText
                timeText.setText(String.valueOf(timeValue) + "\"");

                //With each iteration decrement the time by 1 sec
                timeValue -= 1;

                //This means the user is out of time so onFinished will called after this iteration
                if (timeValue == -1) {

                    //Since user is out of time setText as time up
                    resultText.setText(getString(R.string.timeup));

                    //Since user is out of time he won't be able to click any buttons
                    //therefore we will disable all four options buttons using this method
                    disableButton();
                }
            }

            //Now user is out of time
            public void onFinish() {
                //We will navigate him to the time up activity using below method
                timeUp();
            }
        }.start();

        //This method will set the que and four options
        updateQueAndOptions();


    }


    public void updateQueAndOptions() {

        //This method will setText for que and options
        questionText.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
        buttonA.setText(currentQuestion.getOptA());
        buttonB.setText(currentQuestion.getOptB());
        buttonC.setText(currentQuestion.getOptC());
        buttonD.setText(currentQuestion.getOptD());


        timeValue = 20;

        //Now since the user has ans correct just reset timer back for another que- by cancel and start
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer.start();

        //set the value of coin text
        coinText.setText(String.valueOf(coinValue));
        //Now since user has ans correct increment the coinvalue
        coinValue++;

    }

    public void buttonA(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        buttonPressed(button);
    }
    public void buttonB(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        buttonPressed(button);
    }

    public void buttonC(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        buttonPressed(button);
    }

    public void buttonD(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        buttonPressed(button);
    }

    public void buttonPressed(Button button) {


        if (qid < list.size() - 1) {
            disableButton();
            if (currentQuestion.getOptA().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
                correctDialog();
            } else {
                incorrectDialog();
            }

        } else {
            gameWon();
        }

    }









    //This method will navigate from current activity to GameWon
    public void gameWon() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameWon.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    //This method is called when user ans is wrong
    //this method will navigate user to the activity PlayAgain
    public void gameLostPlayAgain() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayAgain.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    //This method is called when time is up
    //this method will navigate user to the activity Time_Up
    public void timeUp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Time_Up.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    //If user press home button and come in the game from memory then this
    //method will continue the timer from the previous time it left
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    //When activity is destroyed then this will cancel the timer
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    //This will pause the time
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    //On BackPressed
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


    //This dialog is show to the user after he ans correct
    public void correctDialog() {
        final Dialog dialogCorrect = new Dialog(MainGameActivity.this);
        dialogCorrect.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (dialogCorrect.getWindow() != null) {
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            dialogCorrect.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        }
        dialogCorrect.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_correct);
        dialogCorrect.setCancelable(false);
        dialogCorrect.show();

        //Since the dialog is show to user just pause the timer in background
        onPause();




        TextView correctText = (TextView) dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.correctText);
        FButton buttonNext = (FButton) dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.dialogNext);

        //Setting type faces
        correctText.setTypeface(sb);
        buttonNext.setTypeface(sb);

        //OnCLick listener to go next que
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //This will dismiss the dialog
                dialogCorrect.dismiss();
                //it will increment the question number
                qid++;
                //get the que and 4 option and store in the currentQuestion
                currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                //Now this method will set the new que and 4 options
                updateQueAndOptions();
                //reset the color of buttons back to white
                resetColor();
                //Enable button - remember we had disable them when user ans was correct in there particular button methods
                enableButton();
            }
        });
    }


    //INCORRECT//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void incorrectDialog() {
        final Dialog incorrectDialog = new Dialog(MainGameActivity.this);
        incorrectDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (incorrectDialog.getWindow() != null) {
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            incorrectDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        }
        incorrectDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_incorrect);
        incorrectDialog.setCancelable(false);
        incorrectDialog.show();

        //Since the dialog is show to user just pause the timer in background
        onPause();




        TextView IncorrectText = (TextView) incorrectDialog.findViewById(R.id.IncorrectText);
        FButton buttonNext = (FButton) incorrectDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogNext);

        //Setting type faces
        IncorrectText.setTypeface(sb);
        buttonNext.setTypeface(sb);

        //OnCLick listener to go next que
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //This will dismiss the dialog
                incorrectDialog.dismiss();
                //it will increment the question number
                qid++;
                //get the que and 4 option and store in the currentQuestion
                currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                //Now this method will set the new que and 4 options
                updateQueAndOptions();
                //reset the color of buttons back to white
                resetColor();
                //Enable button - remember we had disable them when user ans was correct in there particular button methods
                enableButton();
            }
        });
    }












    //This method will make button color white again since our one button color was turned green
    public void resetColor() {
        buttonA.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
        buttonB.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
        buttonC.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
        buttonD.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
    }

    //This method will disable all the option button
    public void disableButton() {
        buttonA.setEnabled(false);
        buttonB.setEnabled(false);
        buttonC.setEnabled(false);
        buttonD.setEnabled(false);
    }

    //This method will all enable the option buttons
    public void enableButton() {
        buttonA.setEnabled(true);
        buttonB.setEnabled(true);
        buttonC.setEnabled(true);
        buttonD.setEnabled(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: One question at a time, please, and try to shorten the code you are posting. For 1, `if (currentQuestion.getOptA().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer()))` checks if option A is the answer for the current question. Perhaps something like `if (button.getText().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer()))`?

Comment: Thanks! it works now! now figuring out how to make it so that dialog will show in the last question.